# recyclerview scrolling jerking with image loading with glide, also containing other recylerview, webview and video frame

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

I am trying to fetch data from server and showing all in a recyclerview. UI looks like facebook UI. I used inner recyclerview to show image like facebook image gridview, showing user location in map in a webview, there is also a video view to show video from server. i have added photo of my UI. I have tried with different solution on google but nothing worked.

[image]

[image]